# PIP install and Python path

Tags: macos, installation, python, pip

I am using pip install on a mac to get my python requirements for a django website.

I got pip from MacPorts

```
port install pip-2.7
```

Now the problem is the pip installs the packages in a location which is not in my python sys.path.

I just copied this bogus location

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
```

to a location present in my sys.path

```
/Library/Python/2.7/
```

Of course this worked ok, but I will use pip in the future so I need a persistent solution.

The question is how can I alter my sys.path to recognize that crap location or how do I tell pip to install dependencies somewhere else ?

Comment: Cross site duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10461590/425313

Comment: This question makes me queasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path): Set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I have already tried that a few times. I set and export the $PYTHONPATH (which however I don't really understand why is empty). I open another terminal and and echo $PYTHONPATH prints the change.

However, opening a python interpretor and printing sys.path seems unchanged.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. It finally worked.